# A specific question regarding a proof in Hassan Khalil's book, Nonlinear Systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand the proof of a Lemma in the book 'Nonlinear Systems' by Hasaan Khalil (3rd edition). In the Proof of Lemma 3.1, about Lipschitz continuity of vector valued functions, I am unable to follow the evaluation of a derivative using chain rule. My specific question is as follows.

$f:[a,b] \times D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous for some domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exists and is continuous on $[a,b] \times D.$ $t \in [a,b], x \in W,$ and $y \in W$ where $W$ is a convex subset of $D$. Define $\gamma(s)=(1-s)x+sy$ for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\gamma(s) \in D.$ Now define $g(s)=z^\mathrm{T}f(t,\gamma (s))$ where $z \in \mathbb R ^m.$ The derivative of $g(s)$ at a point $s_1 \in (0,1), ~g'(s_1),$ is evaluated using the chain rule and given to be $z^\mathrm{T}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,\gamma(s_1))(y-x)$. I tried working out the derivative but could not get $g'(s_1)=z^\mathrm{T}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t,\gamma(s_1))(y-x)$. Can someone help me understand how we get this using the chain rule?

Comment: Warning: $\partial/\partial x$ is here a lousy notation, as you are also using $x$ in other sense.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $g$ is a sum and each summand of $g$ is the following composition:
$$s\longmapsto(1-s)x+sy\longmapsto f_i(t,(1-s)x+sy)\longmapsto z_if_i(t,(1-s)x+sy)$$
with $t$, $x$, $y$, $z$ constants. Can you continue?